# WiFi connection drops after upgrading firmware

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router

I have a Linksys Wireless N Router (WRT120N). I updated the firmware last week and ever since the wireless communication hasn't been stable. The wired connection is just fine. However, for wireless, some devices (iPhone, Macbook Pro) will connect instantly but then lose signal and the connection will drop. They'll reconnect in a minute or so, however, this time it'll take them 12-20 seconds to get an actual IP address. This connection will also drop in few minutes, but this time lasting longer than the previous time. On Windows 7 machine, the connection will be stable, however, the signal will drop to zero every few minutes.

I have tried several different settings on the router and none of them seem to be working well with all of the wireless devices in the apartment.

Here are some basic information about my router's settings:

- Network Mode: Mixed (B,G,N)
- Channel Width: 40MHz only
- Wide Channel: Auto
- Standard Channel: Auto
- Security Mode: WPA2-Personal
- Encryption: TKIP or AES
- Key Renewal: 3600 Seconds
- MTU: 1500

I scanned the neighborhood and noticed that my router is the only one that's broadcasting on Channel 9 in the vicinity. So, I am out of ideas. What can I try?

Thanks!

Comment: Other non computer devices can use that frequency range of the router, try changing the router channel. Keep changing it until you find the most stable channel.

Answer (score 0):

Will the router support a firmware downgrade so you can confirm your suspicions? Not every upgrade is an improvement and so unless there is a specific reason why you need to upgrade it might be better to go back if you can.

Comment: I upgraded because my roommate once complained that he had problems getting on the WiFi. I should have investigated further rather than just upgrading the firmware. I'll see if I can downgrade the firmware. Problem is Cisco/Linksys no longer makes the older version of the firmware available for download.